# How to submit button value from Bootstrap dialog?

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

I want to get value of button(which is "delete" here) after submit. As you can see below

```
$buttonValue = $_REQUEST['deletebutton'];
            if($buttonValue == 'delete') 
            {....}
```

But Bootstrap dialog box is not submitting the form which extends my button I think. Is there any way to get this value after submit?

```
<form>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button id="deleteButtonId" type="button" name="deletebutton" value="delete" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to use AJAX. Try searching for jQuery AJAX, that handles cross browser compatibility.

Comment: There is no form? I'd use a hidden field

Comment: Just add: `<input type="hidden" value="delete" name="deletebutton" />` into your dialog form (if there's any...).

Comment: @hellzone why wrapping the whole dialog into `form` tag? Where the idea came from?